# Listbox Error On Selection Index

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a listbox control on winform and same is Single Items SelectionMode OR One Items Selection Mode. I am  trying to scroll it from **form_KeyDown** Event as below

```
if ((Keys)e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
{
     if (listBox2.Items.Count >= listBox2.SelectedIndex) 
     {
           listBox2.SelectedIndex++;

     }

 }
```

But it’s throw an error like **“ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled”
Invalid argument of value =23 is not valid for selection index.**

How to get ridoff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ((Keys)e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
{
     if ((listBox2.Items.Count-1) > listBox2.SelectedIndex) 
     {
           listBox2.SelectedIndex++;

     }

 }
```

Remember that if you have 23 items, `SelectedIndex` goes from 0 to 22...

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindex.aspx) on `ListBox.SelectedIndex`:

> A **zero-based** index of the currently selected item. A value of negative
>   one (-1) is returned if no item is selected.

So, I believe you need to change

```
if (listBox2.Items.Count >= listBox2.SelectedIndex)
```

to

```
if (listBox2.Items.Count-1 > listBox2.SelectedIndex)
```

**Please vote Marco's answer as correct, as he pointed this out to me!**

Because if there are 23 items in the listbox, item 23 is actually item 22, item 1 is actually item 0, etc. etc.

Comment: If `Count=23` and `SelectedIndex=22` (so the last one) your `if(...)` will be true and you'll get the same exception

Answer (score 1):

ListBox.SelectedIndex is a zero based array IE the first item will be 0 in the index whereas the Items.Count will always return a value starting at 1.

Please see the following for further information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindex.aspx

Kind Regards, Wayne